# `methods` not loaded when using package::object notation

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm having some trouble executing functions that rely on package **methods** when being run via Rscript. I already know that **methods** is not *attached* via Rscript, but it should be loaded (and usable) by the dependent packages and accessible via their package namespaces, at least I thought so...

Example R script (executed via `Rscript`):

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

sessionInfo()

tryCatch({
    str(lubridate::days(30))
}, error = function(e) {
    print(e)
})

sessionInfo()

tryCatch({
    str(lubridate::days(30))
}, error = function(e) {
    print(e)
})

library(methods)
str(lubridate::days(30))
sessionInfo()
```

Output, with my comments and questions mixed below ...

First, here's the startup `sessionInfo()`:

```
# sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base
```

As expected with `Rscript`, package **methods** is not attached, nor loaded.

Now, what's surprising to me is that I thought the `lubridate::days(30)` call would load **methods**, since the **lubridate** package does "Depend" on **methods**, as verified in **lubridate**'s `DESCRIPTION` file. Instead, I get the error:

```
# tryCatch({
#     str(lubridate::days(30))
# }, error = function(e) {
#     print(e)
# })

<simpleError in .setupMethodsTables(fdef, initialize = TRUE): trying to get slot "group" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots>
```

But now I'm *really* confused, because **methods** *does* seem to have been loaded, as seen with the next `sessionInfo()` call:

```
# sessionInfo()  

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5         tools_3.2.2          lubridate_1.5.6.9000
[4] stringi_1.0-1        methods_3.2.2        stringr_1.0.0
```

Just to be sure (about my confusion), let's try calling `lubridate::days(30)` again:

```
# tryCatch({
#     str(lubridate::days(30))
# }, error = function(e) {
#     print(e)
# })

<simpleError in .setupMethodsTables(fdef, initialize = TRUE): trying to get slot "group" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots>
```

Same error.

OK, now let's explicitly attach **methods** and try the `lubridate::days(30)` call again:

```
# library(methods)
# str(lubridate::days(30))

Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  ..@ .Data : num 0
  ..@ year  : num 0
  ..@ month : num 0
  ..@ day   : num 30
  ..@ hour  : num 0
  ..@ minute: num 0
```

That worked!
What changed by specifically *attaching* **methods**?:

```
# sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] methods   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5         tools_3.2.2          lubridate_1.5.6.9000
[4] stringi_1.0-1        stringr_1.0.0
```

**methods** is now attached (as opposed to loaded-but-not-attached).

I know I could solve all the headaches by simply including `library(methods)` atop scripts, but this seems silly, as I thought loading **methods** would have the same affect to the underlying packages (due to R's package namespacing), without me having to know specifically if any package I use relies on **methods** or not.

Does this seem like an R problem, or possibly a namespace issue with my (perhaps unfortunately chosen) example package, **lubridate**?

Comment: It would be interesting to see the `traceback()` after the error to see the call stack to see which function triggered the error. It may not be a function in `lubridate` itself.

Comment: Still experiencing the same issue for R version 3.4.1 and lubridate_1.6.0 under Win 10.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour with R 3.4.2 on Debain (strech). Specifically I built a service using plumber and hosted in a docker container which starts the script using the command CMD ["Rscript", "plumber.R"] and I'm getting the error above when trying to call a method of an S3 class - when I run the service in RStudio it works fine!